# The HCF of how many distinct pairs of factors of $18000$ is $75$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The first thing i did was i assumed the pair of numbers as $75a,75b$  where a,b are co-prime.
Now a,b have to be factors of $240$ since $18000/75 = 240$ .The prime factorization of $240=2^4*3*5$

1. I consider one of the factor to be $1$ and the other factor will be all the factors of $240$(excluding 1) which is $5*2*2-1=19$
2. i)  one of the factor is factors of $2^4$ (excluding 1) and the other is factors of $3*5$(excluding 1) which is $4$ ways multiplied by $3$ ways = $12$

   ii) similarly one factor is factors of $3$ (excluding 1) and the other factor is factors of $2^4*5$ (excluding 1) which is $1$ way multiplied by $9$ ways = $9$

   iii) similarly we get $9$ ways again when one of the factor is $5$.

Now i think in case $2$ all the cases are counted twice so the total number of cases is actually $(12+9+9)/2=15$

so total pairs of distinct factors whose HCF is $75$ is equal to $15+19=34$.
Now i dont know if the answer is correct or not. Also any suggestions for a more efficient method is appreciated.

Comment: Do these "pairs of factors" need product $18000$, or are they arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

The factors of 3 and 5 can be divided between $a$ and $b$ as $(1,1)$, $(1,3\cdot 5)$, $(1,3)$ and $(1,5)$. ($a$ and $b$ are interchangeable, so to avoid overcounting, we don't consider $(3,1)$ for example).

For the first set, we get 4 possible pairs, corresponding to $(2^k, 1)$, $1\le k\le 4$. For each of the remaining sets, there are 9 possible pairs: $2^k$ can appear in either member (but not both), or in neither, for $4+4+1 = 9$ possibilities. So altogether there are $4+4*9 = 40$ such pairs.

Comment: thank you, i understood that not all cases in my case 2 were counted twice but only some.Your way is much more clear to understand.

Comment: what should i do if the number isn't as small as this one say if the number was 240*
9*25 enumerating all the cases isn't practical then right?